# Вложенные транзакции SQL сервер

Tags: sql, qt, sql-server, odbc, транзакции

Здравствуйте.

Ситуация следующая. Есть SQL Server 2008, в программе используется драйвер QODBC3.
Соединение установлено, данные пишутся/читаются.

Проблема, видимо, в отсутствии понимания принципа работы с вложенными транзакциями. Судя по документации к восьмому серверу, каждый новый BEGIN TRANSACTION  увеличивает счётчик TRANCOUNT на единицу. Каждый COMMIT уменьшает его на 1. Транзакция завершается и фиксируются изменения, когда счётчик станет равен 0. У меня же выходит, что первый же commit завершает транзакцию вне зависимости от того, сколько было BEGIN TRANSACTION. Пусть имеется база и запрос к ней:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC3");
...
query = new QSqlQuery(db);
...
```

Выполняем:

```
db.transaction(); 
      query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1')");
      db.transaction();
            query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2')");
      db.commit(); 
      query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3')");
db.rollback();
```

В результате в таблице оказываются все 3 значения ('1','2','3'). И в SQL SMS видно, что после первого же коммита пропадает единственная активная транзакция. Соответвственно последующий RollBack ничего не делает.

В чём здесь проблема? Я совсем не правильно понял идею со счётчиком открытых транзакций, или просто драйвер/Qt не поддерживают такой функционал? Или я упустил что-то где-то в настройках (сервера/драйвера)?

---

С проверкой возвращаемых значений операций открытия/закрытия транзакций пример выглядит страшнее, но ничего не поделать:

```
    bool ok;

    ok = db.transaction(); qDebug() << "Start transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
    PrintTranCount(); //0

    query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('1')");
    PrintTranCount(); //1

    ok = db.transaction(); qDebug() << "Start transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
    PrintTranCount(); //2

    query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('2')");
    PrintTranCount(); //3

    ok = db.commit(); qDebug() << "Commit transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
    PrintTranCount(); //4

    query->exec("INSERT INTO TestOnly (Value) VALUES('3')");
    PrintTranCount(); //5

    ok = db.rollback();  qDebug() << "Rollback transaction" << " result = " << ok << "; errorText: " << db.lastError().text();
    PrintTranCount(); //6
```

Результат:

```
Start transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   0: 0  
Transaction Count   1: 1   
Start transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "   
Transaction Count   2: 1   
Transaction Count   3: 1   
Commit transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   4: 0  
Transaction Count   5: 0   
Rollback transaction  result =  true ; errorText:  " "  
Transaction Count   6: 0
```

Иными словами, вторая db.transaction() не инкриминирует счётчик совсем и транзакция полностью завершается после первого COMMIT'а. Буду благодарен за любые подсказки по этому поводу.

Вывод значения счётчика транзакций:

```
void PrintTranCount()
{
    static int Num = 0;
    query->exec("SELECT @@TRANCOUNT");query->first();
    qDebug() << "Transaction Count  "<< Num << ": " <<query->value(0).toInt();
    Num++;
}
```

Comment: Поскольку db.transaction, db.commit, db.rollback, если верить документации http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html , есть функции, начните с получения их значений. Может, найдётся, что поанализировать... например, может оказаться, что второй db.transaction возвращает ошибку... Со стороны сервера Вы всё объясняете верно - значит, проблема или в библиотеке, или в драйвере.

Comment: @Akina, ошибок не видать. Сейчас дополню основной пост.

Comment: у вас в тесте первая транзакция ничего и не делает, поэтому счетчик и не меняется мб. перед коммитом (после инсерта) выведите еще счетчик, будет 2, наверное. То есть выводите счетчик транзаций не при начале самой транзации, а после первого действия в этой транзакции

Comment: @teran, проверил. После первого INSERT'а  действительно счётчик показывает единицу. Вот только после второй транзакции и  INSERT'а внутри неё счётчик один чёрт показывает единицу. Получается, что начало второй транзакции не прибавило счётчик и первый же COMMIT полностью закрыл транзакцию. Поправлю основной пост, добавив эти данные.

Comment: я не знаю qt и c++, не знаю какая версия сейчас актуальна и т.п. но вот код https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/odbc/qsql_odbc.cpp.html драйвера odbc, и я что-то вообще не втыкаю, где он там пытается открыть транзакцию. Вижу в `beginTransaction` пытается установить автокоммит и все. В общем, отлаживать сам qt то пробовали? он с открытым кодом поставляется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Краткий ответ**

Вызов метода QSqlDatabase::transaction() не начинает транзакцию в базе, а лишь включает режим "[ручной режим фиксации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/manual-commit-mode)". Для того чтобы начать явную транзакцию, нужно отослать базе непосредственно команду "begin tran".

**Пояснения**

Проблема заключалась в том, что я принимал желаемое поведение драйвера за действительное и поленился залезть в исходники. Спасибо @teran за то, что "ткнул носом" куда надо.

Описание функции bool QSqlDatabase::transaction() гласит:

> Begins a transaction on the database if the driver supports
>   transactions. Returns true if the operation succeeded. Otherwise it
>   returns false.

Из этого описания я сделал ложный вывод о том, что драйвер отправляет базе команду открытия транзакции, что, мягко говоря, не соотносится с действительностью.

Из исходников:

```
bool QSqlDatabase::transaction()
{
    if (!d->driver->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions))
        return false;
    return d->driver->beginTransaction();
}
```

Функция "спрашивает" драйвер о поддержке транзакций, вызывая hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions). Если получает положительный ответ - вызывает метод драйвера beginTransaction().

```
bool QODBCDriver::beginTransaction()
{
    Q_D(QODBCDriver);
    //---------------Проверяем открыта ли база-----------------
    if (!isOpen()) 
    { 
        qWarning("QODBCDriver::beginTransaction: Database not open");
        return false;
    }
    //------Инициализация переменной-параметра значением,-----
    //------отключающим автоматический commit операций--------
    SQLUINTEGER ac(SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF);  
    //-------Устанавливаем этот параметр и проверяем на ошибки-----------------
    SQLRETURN r  = SQLSetConnectAttr(d->hDbc,
                                      SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT,
                                      (SQLPOINTER)size_t(ac),
                                      sizeof(ac));
    if (r != SQL_SUCCESS) {
        setLastError(qMakeError(tr("Unable to disable autocommit"),
                     QSqlError::TransactionError, d));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

В функции beginTransaction(), в свою очередь, единственное производимое действие - отключение автоматического подтверждения изменений в базе. Никаких "begin tran".

В результате, с отключённым автокоммитом база данных при выполнении каждой инструкции начинает [неявную транзакцию](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188317(v=sql.105).aspx). Это (а не сама функция transaction(), как я думал) и приводит к установке счётчика транзакций @TRANCOUNT в единицу. Нет никакой вложенности транзакций в данном случае, она одна и завершается сразу после первого же COMMIT'а.

Функция commit() (как и rollback()) содержит в себе вызов QODBCDriver::endTrans(), который вновь отключает режим неявных транзакций. Это отключение объясняет, почему в моём примере в результирующей таблице была и третья строка (та, что перед ROLLBACK'ом). COMMIT перед отправкой команды вставки этой строки завершил неявную транзакцию и отключил ручной режим фиксации, так что INSERT был автоматически зафиксирован в базе, а rollback() отработал вхолостую.

Answer (score 1):

По поводу того, как работают вложенные транзакции на mssql:

```
use tempdb
go
set nocount on;
SELECT [@@TRANCOUNT]=@@TRANCOUNT ,[XACT_STATE()]=XACT_STATE() ,[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]=CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
begin tran
SELECT [@@TRANCOUNT]=@@TRANCOUNT ,[XACT_STATE()]=XACT_STATE() ,[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]=CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
begin tran
SELECT [@@TRANCOUNT]=@@TRANCOUNT ,[XACT_STATE()]=XACT_STATE() ,[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]=CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
commit
SELECT [@@TRANCOUNT]=@@TRANCOUNT ,[XACT_STATE()]=XACT_STATE() ,[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]=CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
commit
SELECT [@@TRANCOUNT]=@@TRANCOUNT ,[XACT_STATE()]=XACT_STATE() ,[IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS]=CASE WHEN @@OPTIONS & 2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

@@TRANCOUNT XACT_STATE() IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS
----------- ------------ ---------------------
0           0            0
1           1            0
2           1            0
1           1            0
0           0            0
```

Comment: Примерно такого поведения я и ждал от своего кода, но, видимо, QSqlDatabase::transaction() начинает транзакцию каким-то специфическим образом и вызов этой функции не равносилен команде "begin tran". Так и не понял, как средствами Qt вогнать базу в такое состояние, чтобы @@TRANCOUNT показывал 2.
Похоже придётся свою обёртку над QSqlDatabase делать, которая будет сама считать кол-во начатых транзакций и делать COMMIT только при закрытии транзакции внешнего уровня.

Comment: @Eventus а вы не пробовали `begin tran` выполнять в коде? вместо вызова `db.transaction()`

Comment: @teran Каюсь, в исходники не лазил. После переустановки системы, при установке Qt'а их даже скачать забыл. И, видимо, очень даже зря. transaction(), судя по всему, действительно только проверяет, поддерживает ли драйвер транзакции (hasFeature()) и вызывает beginTransaction(), которой по сути просто отключает автокоммит. Всё, как вы и написали. Замена transaction(), commit() и rollback() на непосредственные sql  команды так же всё приводит в норму. Большое спасибо за помощь. Если надумаете оформить ответ - приму как решение.

Comment: @Eventus как я уже написал, с qt и т.п. не знаком, так что писать ответ не буду. Разберетесь более подробно, оформите сами.